# AM-GM inequality basic

Tags: inequality

$a, b, c$ are positive real numbers.

Prove that $$8abc\le (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$

I haven't really gotten anywhere, just tried to open up $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ and got null.

Answer (score 5):

It's really as simple as noting that $a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$, and similarly for $a+c$ and $b+c$, then multiplying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM, we get that
$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab} $$
$$\Rightarrow a+b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$$

Similar manipulations show that
$$ b+c \geq 2 \sqrt{bc}$$
$$ a+c \geq 2 \sqrt{ac}$$

Multiplying all these inequalities together ( this is allowed here, since all numbers involved are positive), we get 
$$ \begin{align}
(a+b)(b+c)(a+c) &\geq (2\sqrt{ab})(2\sqrt{bc})(2\sqrt{ac}) \\
&= 8 \sqrt{ab.bc.ac} \\
&=  8 \sqrt{a^{2} b^{2} c^{2}} \\
&= 8abc
\end{align}
$$
as required.