# If $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=8abc$ prove $a=b=c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For positive numbers $a,b,c$ we have $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=8abc$. Prove $a=b=c$

I tried expanding the expression. after simplifying we have,

$$a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+ca^2+ac^2+bc^2=6abc$$
But not sure how to continue.

I also noticed that we have,

$$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)=(2a)(2b)(2c)$$
$$(a+b)+(a+c)+(b+c)=(2a)+(2b)+(2c)$$
But I don't know if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried AM-GM inequality...?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942608/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM,
$$a+b \geqslant 2\sqrt{ab}$$
with equality if and only if $a=b$.
Multiplying together the three similar inequalities we get
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \geqslant 8abc$$
with equality if and only if $a=b=c$.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about AM-GM on all three numbers and missed that we can use it for each two numbers!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from where you left, you have:
$b(a-c)^2+a(b-c)^2+ b^2c+ca^2-2abc=0$,which is same as $$b(a-c)^2+a(b-c)^2+c(b-a)^2=0$$ So you now have sum of three non-negative numbers equal to $0$. Can you take it from here?